# Locating files and dependencies I installed via Homebrew and uninstalling them properly

Tags: terminal, cmake, macports, libusb, libtool

I'm trying to hack an [Xbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox) [Kinect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect) and have followed the instructions located [here](http://blog.nelga.com/setup-microsoft-kinect-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/). Through this process I installed the following files.

- XQuartz
- [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake)
- [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts)
- libtool
- [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb)
- OpenNI
- SensorKinect
- NiTE

I've been advised to uninstall these and reinstall them again to make sure they have installed correctly. I'm having a hard time locating some of these files. OpenNI, SensorKinect and NiTE I have installed in their own file on my desktop. So uninstalling these "I assume" would be just as simple as highlighting them, right click and delete.

However, the other files CMake, MacPorts, libtool and libusb I'm having an awful time locating their directory from using the terminal. I installed libtool and libusb from [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) I know for sure. But like I said I cannot locate these two files. CMake and MacPorts are just invisible because I cannot for the life of me figuring out where I saved these two.

How do I locate these files? Also once I locate these files, how do I delete them? I know sometimes you need to do a uninstall rather than just doing a delete.

Comment: MacPorts will install its stuff in /opt/local. MacPorts is a package manager you use to install other software (using the port command). If you remove /opt/local you will also remove all packages installed using MacPorts. To uninstall the homebrew stuff, look at the homebrew documentation. How did you install CMake?

Answer (score 0):

I just caught your question, and saw you were referencing my blog post. I've just posted a new tutorial on how to uninstall all of these that might help you.  Check out: http://blog.nelga.com/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-kinect-drivers-xquartz-cmake-macports-openni-nite-sensorkinect-on-your-mac/

As Vortexfive mentioned though - be careful with MacPorts if you're using it for other things.